# SSL化したサイトが保護されてない通信と出てしまいます。

Tags: aws, laravel, amazon-ec2

EC2上にあるWebアプリをSSL化し該当のサイトアクセスしたら保護されていない通信と出ます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
原因は以下のデベロッパーツールから、恐らくロゴに使っている画像がhttps化されていないことが要因なようです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
EC2上のlaravel/public/imagesというフォルダに画像を入れているので表示できるはずなのですが、シンボリックリンクが必要なのでしょうか？または別の処置が必要でしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

追記
画像タグ

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/logo.png') }}" class="logo mr-1" width="100" height="50">
```

**form.blade.php**

```
<form class="active-cyan-4" action="{{ url('/search')}}">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keyword" value="@if (isset( $keyword )) $keyword @endif" placeholder="xxxxxxx">
</form>
```

**nav.blade.php** （ここでform.blade.phpを読み込んでいます）

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
 @include('form')
</ul>
```

Comment: その画像へのリンクをhttps://~に書き直したらどうなりますか。もしくは相対パスに書き直してみるとどうでしょうか。

Comment: 画像のリンクを書き直すとはhtmlの画像を表示しているタグを書き換えるという事でしょうか？

Comment: 実際<img src="~”>などでファイルを指定していると思いますが、そのパスを書き直してみてください。あるいは現在どういった書き方をしているかこちらに開示してもらえたら、アドバイスが集まりやすいと思います。

Comment: 現在のパスの書き方を追記しました。このasset（）の部分をhttps://~に書き直すという事でしょうか？

Comment: 1つ目の警告を読む限り、<form action=...> の問題であって、画像のエラーは関係ないかもしれません。

Comment: 確かにhttp://xxxxx.com/searchがセキュリティで保護されていないとでてます。ローカルのソースファイルにはform.blade.phpがありそこにある<form＞が読み込まれていないのでしょうか。。コードを追記しました。

Answer (score 0):

通常はLaravelではリクエストのプロトコルでHTTPかHTTPSを切り分けているはずなので、
おそらくEC2とロードバランサーの間の通信はHTTPなんですかね？
あとはLaravelのバージョンが古いかも？？
何らかの理由で自動的にHTTPSに変わらないものと推察されます。

強制的にHTTPSで吐き出すように[secure_asset](https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/ja/helpers.html#method-secure-asset)を使ってみてください。

```
<img src="{{ secure_asset('/images/logo.png') }}" class="logo mr-1" width="100" height="50">
```

Comment: EC2とロードバランサーの間の通信はhttpです。タグを上記のように変えてみましたが、結果は変わらず、Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()とでてしまいます